# rake test:functionals throwing syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

When I run the rake task "test:functionals" for my RoR app, it produces this error:

```
>rake test:functionals

rake aborted!
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:380: syntax error, unexpec
ted keyword_end, expecting $end

Tasks: TOP => test:functionals => test:prepare => db:test:prepare => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => db:load_conf
ig
```

I have checked my code for syntax errors. Why would transactions.rb have a syntax error?

Comment: My experience is that this happens when you're missing an `end` keyword at the end of a block, even if the error message is pointing to a file within the Rails framework.

Answer (score 1):

You have unmatching blocks in **your code**, its not in transactions.rb., even if it says it's on transactions.rb its most probably not.

Double check your block openers such as `do` `class` `def`

Also check for `.` trailing in methods or objects

Example: `variable.length.`

Comment: That makes sense, but I cannot locate any syntax errors. I can run and use the application without any errors. I'm using an IDE (RubyMine) which checks Ruby syntax. It has a code inspector which I ran, but doesn't turn up anything.

Comment: don't trust rubymine always. Sometimes it tells "something" not found, but actually it exists and works nicely.

Comment: maybe try running each of your functional tests separated to find the one with the error?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I used RubyInstaller to install the latest version of Ruby and re-installed my bundle. It works now. I have no idea why that made the difference... 

I'll keep in mind the possibility of a syntax error in my code in case I encounter this again.